# How to set a correct session expired for my code?

Tags: c#, session-timeout, expired-sessions

I have a code that doing the popup message for the session expired, as following. However, this code cannot do a correct counting session. When run the program, it will direct popup the session expired message which didn't follow the time that I had set. I know that why my message will popup so early because in my

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, strconfirm, false);
```

I didn't add in the "timeout" so it is not executed as I want, but how to add it? when I try to add it in, it will result as input format error. Can someone assist me for this problem?

```
string csname = "timeoutWarning";
Type cstype = this.GetType();
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname))
{
    var timeout = HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout * 60 * 1000;
    string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Your login session is about to expire. Do you want to extend it?')){window.location.href='../login.aspx'}</script>";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, strconfirm, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are no where setting the timeout!**
Extract your java script code to function say `SessionTimeOutHandler()` and call that while sesssion expires:

```
 string strconfirm = "<script>" + 
                     "window.setTimeout('SessionTimeOutHandler()', 60000);" + 
"function SessionTimeOutHandler() { "+
"    if(!window.confirm('Your login session is about to expire. Do you want to extend it?'))"
+"   {window.location.href='../login.aspx'}</script>"; }";
```

Now, just replace your strconfirm initialization statement. It should work for you!

Comment: thanks to your solution but how the popup message can be REPEATED show when it is expired?

Thanks & regards